# In XAML, is it possible to define a global constant style without specifying the TargetType

Tags: xaml

I would like to define my logo color as a style then apply that color wherever.  Something like this:

```
<Style x:Name="LogoBlue">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#607C8C" />
</Style> 

<TextBlock Background="{StaticResource LogoBlue}">Blah Blah</TextBlock>
```

Is it possible to define a color constant as a static resource?

Answer (score -1):

Define a brush as a resource in your App.xaml, then you can refer to it by its key.

As the colour is a fixed colour the PresentationOptions allows more efficient use of the brush as you will not change it's colour.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="PresentationOptions"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LogoBlue" Color="#607C8C" PresentationOptions:Freeze="True"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```